# Schedule a job based on output of another job

Tags: sql-server-2008

On Server1, i want to schedule a job (JobTest). I want to schedule this once another job(JobLive) is completed.
Job Live is on Another server (Server2)
How this could be done.
Please respond with your valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

Jobs can only be scheduled to run based on a given time of day.   They cannot be scheduled to run based on the completion of another job or any other type of condition.

One way to get what you seem to want to is to have the first job add a record to a table that the second job will have access to, and put a step in the second job to check the table, and if the record is not there in the table, don't do anything.   Then you would need to schedule the second job to run throughout a range of time, so that it keeps trying until the record is there in the table.   Then when the second job completes, it deletes the record from the table, so that it won't run again until the first job runs again.